# snapshot and restore in 3 node elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, restore, snapshot

so i am trying to perform snapshot and restore on 3 node cluster in elasticsearch 8.7 through nfs.but when i am putting the path.repo same path of shared directory so its giving me that this path.repo is not accessible.

i tried doing this snapshot and restore through nfs i created nfs server on one machine and created 3 nfs client on 3 nodes and they are able to communicate, when i am giving the path.repo (shared directory).then its showing its not accessible in elasticsearch log.

the error is : error is : "reason": "[rep3] [[FOZ63vx_RAiD46C5vTndJA, 'org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-1][192.168.xx.xxx:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]'], [lM0JnpvIR5eugzv-9i5Lw, 'org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-3][192.168.xx.xxx:9300][internal:admin/repository/verify]']]",

"suppressed": [

{

"type": "repository_verification_exception",

"reason": "[rep3] store location [/var/nfs/elasticsearch2] is not accessible on the node [{node-1}{FOZ63vx_RAiD46C5vTndJA}{1N_QFYKXTQ6GPUV1YC2ELQ}{node-1}{192.168.xx.xxx}{192.168.xx.xxx:9300}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.1}{ml.machine_memory=16778862592, ml.allocated_processors=4, ml.max_jvm_size=8388608000, ml.allocated_processors_double=4.0, xpack.installed=true}]"

Comment: We agree that the NFS is accessible from all 3 nodes ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same `path.repo` for all nodes and in all nodes elasticsearch.yml you should define the same `path.repo`.

It looks like node-1 and node-3 don't have access to `/var/nfs/elasticsearch2`

ssh into node-1 and check `df -kh` make sure the path is mounted.

Please note that, you need to restart Elasticsearch after updating the elasticsearch.yml

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-filesystem-repository.html

Comment: path is already mounted. even they are communicating too like if i am making a file on the node 1 machine then i can see the same file on node 3 machine.